# Sort eigenvectors by eigenvalue and assign to variables

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have the following question:

Let `T = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 3}}`, I know that its eigenvalues, in a decreasing order, are 4, 0 and -1. Mathematica displays eigenvalues and shows the corresponding eigenvectors, in order of the eigenvalue’s decreasing absolute value.

I would like to assign to a vector `n1` the eigenvector of `T` corresponding to the maximum eigenvalues, to `n2` the eigenvector related to the intermediate eigenvalues, and to `n3` the eigenvector related to the minimum eigenvalue.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors jointly:

```
T = {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 3}};
Transpose[ReverseSort[Transpose[Eigensystem[T]]]]
(*    {{4, 0, -1}, {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {-2, 0, 1}}}    *)
```

Assign to the desired variables:

```
{eval, {n1, n2, n3}} = Transpose[ReverseSort[Transpose[Eigensystem[T]]]]
(*    {{4, 0, -1}, {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {-2, 0, 1}}}    *)
```

#### Update with eigenvector normalization

Assign the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to separate variables:

```
{eval, evec} = Transpose[ReverseSort[Transpose[Eigensystem[T]]]]
(*    {{4, 0, -1}, {{1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {-2, 0, 1}}}    *)
```

Assign variables to the normalized eigenvectors:

```
{n1, n2, n3} = Normalize /@ evec
(*    {{1/Sqrt[5], 0, 2/Sqrt[5]},
       {0, 1, 0},
       {-2/Sqrt[5], 0, 1/Sqrt[5]}}    *)
```

Comment: ReverseSort is not a valid command for Mathematica 11

Comment: Then use `Reverse[Sort[...]]` instead: `Transpose[Reverse[Sort[Transpose[Eigensystem[T]]]]]`. Or just use `Sort` and reverse the order of the assignments to `{eval, {n3, n2, n1}}`.

Comment: Thanks Roman! I was trying with a cumbersome nested If conditions...
Morevoer, is it possible to insert in this line the normalization of such vectors?

Comment: Yes, see update